# Adding an argument to \part macro

Tags: titlesec, optional-arguments, parts, arguments

I want to be able to call the part macro like this:

`\part{Introdução Geral}{(2015)}`

Having the year as a kind of subtitle.

I can call:

`\part{Introdução Geral\\\\ \Large(2015)}`

But this applies the year to the whole title of the part, what messes up with table of contents.
I couldn't come with any solution yet. I thought in using the titleformat from titlesec package to customize the \part macro but I need to pass in an argument and call it before the pagebreak.

I appreciate any help in advance.

The desired effect is this:
[image: Desired effect]

Comment: Okay, I found out that I call \part[Introdução Geral]{Introdução Geral\\\\ \\Large (2015)} and have the desired effect. Still, it would be nice to solve this is with an additional argument.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out

```
\newcommand{\mypart}[2]{
  \part[#1]{#1\\\Large#2}
}
```